# BST<string> vs vector<string> + binary search

Tags: c++

Which is better (space/time) to find certain strings:

1. To use a vector of strings (alphabetically ordered) and a binary search.
2. To use a BST of strings (also ordered alphabetically).

Or are both similar?

Comment: The preferred method is to profile.

Answer (score 3):

Both have advantages, and it is going to depend on what your usage scenario is.

A sorted vector will be more efficient if your usage scenario can be broken into phases: load everything, then sort it once, then look things up without changing anything.

A tree structure will work better for you if your scenario involves inserting, searching, and removing things at different times, and you can't break it into phases. (In this case, a vector can add overhead, since inserting in the middle is expensive.)

There's a really good discussion of this in [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629), and there's a sorted vector implementation in [Loki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loki-lib/).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the binary search tree is balanced (which it will be if you are using std::set), then both of these are O(n) space and O(log n) time.  So theoretically they are comparable.

In practice, the vector will take up somewhat less space and thus might be slightly faster thanks to locality effects.  But probably not enough to matter, and since std::set supports O(log n) insertion, O(log n) deletion, and has a straightforward interface, I would recommend std::set.

That said...  If all you care about is queries and you do not need to enumerate the strings in order, std::tr1::unordered_set (or boost::unordered_set or C++0x std::unordered_set) will be much faster than either, especially if the set is large.  Hash tables rock.

Comment: Hash tables may rock in some cases, but you can't use them in security sensitive scenarios because of the worst-case linear search. An attacker who controls the keys of the hash table can create contrived keys to cause denials of service by forcing linear time lookups. Trees are better as a general purpose data structure; hash tables should be switched to only in cases where the input does not control the keys, and where profiling shows that things are faster with the hash table.

Comment: @Billy: on the (relatively rare) occasion that the worst case guarantee of a tree is important, you can use a hash table with a balanced tree (instead of linear list) for collision resolution. This can give O(1) expected, and O(log N) worst case.

Comment: @Billy: The "security sensitive" scenario is not the common case, but you are right that hash tables are not so great for them (unless maybe you salt the keys with data outside the attacker's control).  But in the real world where 99.99% of applications are not security-sensitive, hash tables clobber trees for performance.  Modern CPUs are slooow to access random memory, and they get slower (relative to core speed) every generation.  Since physics is local, this trend is very likely to continue.

Comment: @Nemo: I don't follow that thinking. Hash tables usually have more overhead than trees in terms of memory use. Additionally, if you access the same part of a tree often, that part will likely be on the same cache line. Accessing similar pieces in a hash table inevitably spreads what you're doing across a large range of pages. Which will be faster will depend on access patterns. You have to profile to find out; neither structure is inherently faster than the other. (This is of course assuming your tree implementation is halfway decent and groups lots of nodes onto single pages or cache lines)

Comment: @Billy: It's not about total memory; it's about random pointer chasing.  With a tree, you have to chase O(log n) random pointers as you walk the tree.  With a hash table, it is closer to O(1) in practice.  If your set is large and your lookups are random (which I admit I am assuming), the hash table _will_ dominate.  At least, in my experience, they always do.  (I have no argument with profiling both, of course.)